# XeLaTeX giving me many gibberish errors when trying to compile beamer presentation

Tags: beamer, compiling, compilation-error

I am writing a beamer presentation and when I try to compile it with running `xelatex chessboxing.tex chessboxing.pdf`, everything goes fine until here:

```
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text>
                $
l.41 \end{frame}

?

! LaTeX Error: Command $ invalid in math mode.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...

l.41 \end{frame}

?

! LaTeX Error: Command \ttfamily invalid in math mode.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...

l.41 \end{frame}

?
! Missing } inserted.
<inserted text>
                }
l.41 \end{frame}

?
! Missing \endgroup inserted.
<inserted text>
                \endgroup
l.41 \end{frame}

?
! Missing \endgroup inserted.
<inserted text>
                \endgroup
l.41 \end{frame}

?
! Undefined control sequence.
\Url@FormatString ...ndafter \UrlLeft \Url@String
                                                  \UrlRight \m@th $
l.41 \end{frame}

?
! Extra }, or forgotten $.
<recently read> }

l.41 \end{frame}

?
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text>
                $
l.41 \end{frame}

?
! Missing } inserted.
<inserted text>
                }
l.41 \end{frame}

?
! Missing } inserted.
<inserted text>
                }
l.41 \end{frame}

?
! Too many }'s.
\beamer@doifinframe ...2.0}, от Wikimedia Commons}
                                                   \end {beamer@frameslide}
l.41 \end{frame}

?

! LaTeX Error: \begin{document} ended by \end{beamer@framepauses}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...

l.41 \end{frame}

?
! Extra \endgroup.
<recently read> \endgroup

l.41 \end{frame}

?
! Too many }'s.
\endbeamer@frameslide ...amer@framepauses}\egroup
                                                  \ifx \beamer@frametitle \@...
l.41 \end{frame}

?
! Undefined control sequence.
\endbeamer@frameslide ...box \else \beamer@zoomer
                                                  \fi \beamer@undolabels \be...
l.41 \end{frame}

?

! LaTeX Error: \begin{document} ended by \end{beamer@frameslide}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...

l.41 \end{frame}

?
! Extra \endgroup.
<recently read> \endgroup

l.41 \end{frame}

?
```

I just press enter and it compiles, but then my presentation hase some issues. Also, I checked some of the errors and they all seem like gibberish. Here is my LaTeX file:

```
\documentclass[bulgarian]{beamer}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{babel}
\babelfont{rm}{FreeSans}
\setmainfont{FreeSans}
\setsansfont{FreeSans}
\setmonofont{FreeMono}
\usetheme{Bergen}
\usecolortheme{seagull}
\title{Шахбокс}
\author{Явор Узунов 5А клас}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Шахбокс}
Шахбоксът е хибриден спорт. В него се играе бокс и шах. Хубав е, защото развива и мозъка, и здравословното тяло.
\includegraphics{/home/yav/Schachboxen1.jpg}

{\tiny"Schachboxen1.jpg" от WCBO, CC BY 3.0 DE \url{https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0/de/deed.en}, от Wikimedia Commons}
\end{frame}



\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Правила}
% \section[Section]{Рундове и печелене}
Има 6 рунда бърз шах и 5 рунда бокс. Започва се с шаха. Обявява се победа при:
\begin{itemize}[noitemsep]
\item нокаут
\item мат
\item свършване на времето на играч в бърз шах (9 минути)
\item по преценка на съдията
\item отказ от участие
\end{itemize}
Ако шахматните игри завършат с равен резултат, побеждава този, който има повече точки в бокса, а ако и там е равно, печели този, който е играл с черните фигур>
% \section[Section]{Класове по тежест}
\includegraphics[height=2cm]{/home/yav/Chess_Boxing_2007_(3).jpg}\includegraphics[height=2cm]{/home/yav/Chess_Boxing_2007_(4).jpg}

{\tiny Chess_Boxing_2007_(3).jpg и Chess_Boxing_2007_(4).jpg от Sascha Pohflepp, CC BY 2.0 \url{https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/2.0}, от Wikimedia Com>
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `Chess_Boxing_2007`  `_` is math only command for subscript, use `Chess\_Boxing\_2007`

Comment: If I change the images to `example-image` so it can be run your example gives the error `! File ended while scanning use of \frame.`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks, the problem were the _'s.

Comment: Since `\babelfont` will set `[Script=Cyrillic, Language=Bulgarian]` if the current language is Bulgarian, many fonts that default to Russian forms will work correctly for Bulgarian. If you do **not** want this, set up the language with `\babelprovide[import, main, language=Default]{bulgarian}`

Comment: You want to remove your `\setmainfont`, `\setsansfont` and `setmonofont` commands, which are redundant with `\babelfont`. Add `\babelfont{sf}{FreeSans}` and `\babelfont{tt}{FreeMono}` to `\babelfont{rm}{FreeSans}`, which you already have.

Answer (score 1):

A simpler test file is

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\title{Шахбокс}
\author{Явор Узунов 5А клас}
\begin{document}



\begin{frame}
Chess_Boxing_2007_(3).jpg и Chess_Boxing_2007_(4).jpg от 
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

which produces the error that you show (only ever look at the first error, later errors are often spurious)

```
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.12 \end{frame}
                
?
```

That tells you that you have used some math constrict in text mode, so TeX has inserted a `$`  to get into math.

Admittedly due to the nature of beamer the error message is less than clear about where the error is. However 9 times out of 10 this is a `_`  which turns out to be the case here, however TeX can be persuaded to give more helpful message...

Add

```
\errorcontextlines=100
```

to the document preamble and re-run

This time the error message is more verbose.

```
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
<to be read again> 
                   _
\beamer@doifinframe ...n {beamer@frameslide}Chess_
                                                  Boxing_2007_(3).jpg и Ches...

\iterate ...e {\beamer@whichframes }\beamer@donow 
                                                  \ifbeamer@twoscreenstext \...

\loop ...elax \expandafter \iterate \fi }\iterate 
                                                  \let \iterate \relax 
\beamer@howtotreatframe ...ame by 1\relax \repeat 
                                                  \beamer@writeslidentry \be...
l.13 \end{frame}
                
?
```

Note the line break after `Chess_` showing that TeX was processing text up to that point at the point it made the error. That is, it is exactly highlighting the bad input.